# Labeling a d3 sunburst chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to label a d3 sunburst chart. For each arc slice, a line is to extend from its center to outwards (in same direction/angle).

[image]
I'm doing this

```
el.append('svg:line')
        .attr('x1',function(d){ return self.arc.centroid(d)[0] })
        .attr('y1',function(d){ return self.arc.centroid(d)[1] })
        .attr('x2',function(d){
            let angle = (self.arc.endAngle()(d) - self.arc.startAngle()(d))*(180/Math.PI);
            let [cx,cy] = self.arc.centroid(d);
            let radius = self.arc.outerRadius()(d);
            return cx + radius*Math.sin(angle);
        })
.attr('y2',function(d){
            let angle = (self.arc.endAngle()(d) - self.arc.startAngle()(d))*(180/Math.PI);
            let [cx,cy] = self.arc.centroid(d);
            let radius = self.arc.outerRadius()(d);
            return cy + radius*Math.cos(angle);
        })
```

My angle calculation may be wrong, but im not sure why is it uniform for every line.

> I want the lines to extend outwards, instead as you can see they extend rightwards.

I have seen Pie chart examples where we have an **outer arc**. That would not work here, because in a sunburst chart, I may have multiple slices on the same angle.

https://codepen.io/metalsushi/pen/KXzXOw Here's a codepen with sample code.

Comment: idk what you asking, please give the code my this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060170/how-do-i-externalize-my-d3-v4-pie-chart-labels/46108896#46108896

Comment: Anyway you can create a code snippet example that we can take a look at?

Comment: added codepen snippet

Comment: why not make an arc over your sun that have an outer arc, then display none, append your data and take only attr to build the function