# d3 v4 donut chart has text and poylines that overlap with small values

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to figure out how to arrange the labels so that they do not overlap. Here is a picture of the chart

[image]

As you can see, with really small values, the text labels overlap. I tried to iterate over each text element and modify it's position, but that doesn't seem to be working. You can see at the bottom of this function that I tried to get the position of each text element and then modify it. What am I doing wrong? I've been at it for hours.

```
   _renderDonutChart() {
    let self = this;
    // console.log("Donut Chart is beginning render")
    let textOffset = 14;
    self.graph.data[0].forEach(function (d) {
        d.value = +d.value;
    })
    console.log(self.graph.data[0])
    let boxSize = (self.options.radius + self.options.padding) * 2;
    let parent = d3.select(self.ui.parent);
    //let color = d3.scaleOrdinal(['#dc8710', '#9e3400', '#f19b12']);
    let color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);
    let svg = parent.append('svg')
        .attr('width', boxSize * 2)
        .attr('height', boxSize)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(-111,0)')
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + boxSize + ',' + boxSize / 2 + ')');
    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'slices')
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "labelName")
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "labelValue")
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "lines")
    svg.append("div")
        .attr("class", "progress-circle__box progress-circle__box--victorytype")
    let arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(self.options.radius - self.options.border)
        .outerRadius(self.options.radius);
    let outerArc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius((self.options.radius - self.options.border) * 1.2)
        .outerRadius((self.options.radius) * 1.2);
    let legendRectSize = self.options.radius * 0.05;
    let legendSpacing  = self.options.radius * 0.02;
    let pie = d3.pie()
        .value(function(d) { return d.value; })
        .sort(null);
    let slice = svg.select('.slices')
        .selectAll('path.slice')
        .data(pie(self.graph.data[0]))
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr("class", "slice")
        .attr('d', arc)
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
            return color(d.data.label);
        })
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || 0;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                return arc(interpolate(t));
            };
        })

    function midAngle(d){
        return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
    }
    let text = svg.select(".labelName").selectAll("text")
        .data(pie(self.graph.data[0]))
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr('class', 'label')
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr('transform', function(d) {

            // effectively computes the centre of the slice.
            // see https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#arc_centroid
            var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);

            // changes the point to be on left or right depending on where label is.
            pos[0] = self.options.radius * 0.97 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
            return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
        })
        .style('text-anchor', function(d) {
            // if slice centre is on the left, anchor text to start, otherwise anchor to end
            return (midAngle(d)) < Math.PI ? 'start' : 'end';
        })
        .style("fill", "white")
        .text(function(d) {
            return (" " + d.data.label+": " +d.value+"");
        })
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = self.options.radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return "translate("+ pos +")";
            };
        })
        .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start":"end";
            };
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return (d.data.label+": "+d.value+"%");
        })
    let polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
        .data(pie(self.graph.data[0]))
        .enter()
        .append("polyline")
        .attr('points', function(d) {
            var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
            pos[0] = self.options.radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
            return [arc.centroid(d), outerArc.centroid(d), pos]
        })
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px");

    let prev;
    text.each(function(d, i) {
        if(i > 0) {
            let thisbb = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
                prevbb = prev.getBoundingClientRect();
            // move if they overlap
            console.log(thisbb.left);
            console.log(prevbb.right);
            if(!(thisbb.right < prevbb.left ||
                thisbb.left > prevbb.right ||
                thisbb.bottom < prevbb.top ||
                thisbb.top > prevbb.bottom)) {
                var ctx = thisbb.left + (thisbb.right - thisbb.left)/2,
                    cty = thisbb.top + (thisbb.bottom - thisbb.top)/2,
                    cpx = prevbb.left + (prevbb.right - prevbb.left)/2,
                    cpy = prevbb.top + (prevbb.bottom - prevbb.top)/2,
                    off = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ctx - cpx, 2) + Math.pow(cty - cpy, 2))/2;
                d3.select(this).attr("transform",
                    "translate(" + Math.cos(((d.startAngle + d.endAngle - Math.PI) / 2)) *
                    (self.options.radius + textOffset + off) + "," +
                    Math.sin((d.startAngle + d.endAngle - Math.PI) / 2) *
                    (self.options.radius + textOffset + off) + ")");
            }
        }
        prev = this;
    });

    // console.log("Donut Chart is ending render")
}
```

Comment: Can you give different `dy` values based on a function of the angle: `function(d) { return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .02 ? .35 : .7; }`?

Comment: I hope you have seen this https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/11/solving-d3-label-placement-constraint-relaxing/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The best solution for me was to increase the size of the Svg area (based on current window) and add some padding to the legends based on the radius of the donut.

ie:

```
   var margin = {top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 40};
   var svgWidth = window.innerWidth - (window.innerWidth/4);
   var width = svgWidth,
      height = (Math.min(width) / 2) + 100,
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 3;

   var legendRectSize = (radius * 0.08);
   var legendSpacing = (radius * 0.05);
```

This worked for me until the item count became too high. I amended from labels around the edge to display in the center, on slice/arc hover events. (There is an animation on the data value, which is why they are slanted in this snapshot)

[image: D3 Donut Chart Amended labels]

I thought this made the unreadable data labels less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you had same problem with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060170/how-do-i-externalize-my-d3-v4-pie-chart-labels), you need to add more margin to your pie chart segment, assume your pie return 3% value, and you draw a text with line, it will stack on another, you need to devine margin if that value < 3 draw text with y+margin

```
 if(percent<3){
       o[1] 
       pos[1] += i*15
       }
       //return [label.centroid(d),[o[0],0[1]] , pos];
        return [label.centroid(d),[o[0],pos[1]] , pos];
      })
```

try to append this code structure to your chart