# How to Dynamically Place Labels in D3 Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart

I'm using D3JS in my application and I have a Pie chart in my application. And from searching on the internet and some forums I was able to identify a way to show the pie chart labels outside the pie chart(Earlier they were shown inside the pie chart itself). But even though I took the label outside the Pie now it's sometimes getting overlapped with Pie when the label name is long. As well as when the pie slice is getting smaller the names get overlapped with each other. Is there a way to have these labels dynamically without getting overlapped.

Following is the sample code that I used.

```
    var data2018 = [{
    "label": "Argentina",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "label": "Madagascar",
    "value": 10
  },
  {
    "label": "Sri Lanka",
    "value": 15
  },
  {
    "label": "United States of America",
    "value": 13
  },
  {
    "label": "Iceland",
    "value": 17
  },
  {
    "label": "Australia",
    "value": 23
  },
  {
    "label": "Bulgeria",
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "label": "Saudi Arabia",
    "value": 8
  },
  {
    "label": "United Arab Emirates",
    "value": 5
  }
];



  var data = data2018;


const margin = 80;
const w = 1000 - 2 * margin;
const h = 550 - 2 * margin;
var r = h / 2;
var color = d3.scale.category20c();

d3.selectAll("#container-pie > *").remove();

var vis = d3.select('#container-pie').append('g').append('svg:svg').data([data]).attr("width", w).attr("height", h).append("svg:g").attr('x', 10).attr('y', 20)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + 1.2 * r + ")");

var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
  return d.value;
});

// declare an arc generator function
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(r + 30);


// select paths, use arc generator to draw
var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice").data(pie).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "slice");
arcs.append("svg:path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    // log the result of the arc generator to show how cool it is :)
    console.log(arc(d));
    return arc(d);
  })
  .on("mouseenter", function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("stroke", "white")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("d", arcOver)
    // .attr("stroke-width",6);
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function(d) {
    d3.select(this).transition()
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("stroke", "none");
  })
  .on("click", function(d) {});

// add the text
//             arcs.append("svg:text").attr("transform", function(d){
//                 d.innerRadius = 0;
//                 d.outerRadius = r;
//                 return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";}).attr("text-anchor", "middle").text( function(d, i) {
//                 return data[i].label;}
//             );


var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(r - 40)
  .innerRadius(r - 40);

arcs.append("svg:text").attr("transform", function(d) {
  var c = labelArc.centroid(d);
  return "translate(" + c[0] * 1.4 + "," + c[1] * 1.8 + ")";
}).attr("text-anchor", "middle").text(function(d, i) {
  return data[i].label;
});
```

Is there a way to get something like that done. Following screenshot shows an example from Highcharts. 
[image: Highcharts example]

Comment: I think you should check answer to similal question https://stackoverflow.com/a/46108896/9820085

Comment: does anyone get a solution to this scenario?

Comment: I've already pasted link to very similar problem in previous comment. Follow the link

Comment: @KamilNiski thanks